# Can I erase GSON Time mark? ex) AM/PM

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, gson

I use GSON to change the object to json. Also, set and use the code below. As a result, the desired timestamp was obtained.

```
@Bean
public Gson gson() {
    return new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new AnnotationBasedExclusionStrategy())
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            .create();
}
```

However, there is a mark like AM and PM behind the time.

I hope 13:00:00 to 13:00:00 Not 1:00:00 PM

What should I do to get the results I want? Can existing timestamp results be kept together?

ToString Method shows desired result...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_work_system")
public class WorkSystem {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String work_system_type;


@Column(nullable=false)
private Time work_start_time;

@Column(nullable=false)
private Time work_end_time;

@Column(nullable=false)
private Time rest_start_time;

@Column(nullable=false)
private Time rest_end_time;

@Column(nullable=false,columnDefinition="BOOLEAN DEFAULT false")
private Boolean deleted=false;

@CreationTimestamp
private Timestamp created_at; 

@UpdateTimestamp
private Timestamp updated_at;
}
```

//ToString Method

```
WorkSystem [id=1, work_system_type=탄력 근무제, work_start_time=09:00:00, work_end_time=18:00:00, rest_start_time=12:00:00, rest_end_time=13:00:00, deleted=false, created_at=2020-01-31 12:18:13.595343, updated_at=2020-01-31 12:18:13.595343]
```

//ToJson(Gson)

```
{"id":1,"work_system_type":"탄력 근무제","work_start_time":"09:00:00 오전","work_end_time":"06:00:00 오후","rest_start_time":"12:00:00 오후","rest_end_time":"01:00:00 오후","deleted":false,"created_at":"2020-01-31 12:18:13","updated_at":"2020-01-31 12:18:13"}
```

[image]